# Pandas multiply 2 series of different dimensions to give dataframe

Tags: pandas, multiplication

I have a series;

```
Red    33
Blue   44
Green  22
```

And also this series;

```
0   100
1   100
2   100
3   200
4   200
5   200
```

I want to multiply these in a way to give the following dataframe

```
   Red   Blue   Green
0  330   440   220
1  330   440   220
2  330   440   220
3  660   880   440
4  660   880   440
5  660   880   440
```

Can anyone see a simply / tidy way this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC assuming `s` is the name of the first series  and `s1` is the name of the second series, try:

```
m=s.to_frame().T
pd.DataFrame(m.values*s1.values[:,None],columns=m.columns)
```

---

```
    Red  Blue  Green
0  3300  4400   2200
1  3300  4400   2200
2  3300  4400   2200
3  6600  8800   4400
4  6600  8800   4400
5  6600  8800   4400
```